# Very high performance .Net-based engine for handling web requests

Tags: .net

I have a need for a simple, lightweight .Net-based web server engine that will comfortably serve hundreds (or even thousands) of simultaneous requests without breaking a sweat.

I love the idea of node.js but it's only got one .Net port and it seems to have some significant limitations in the forming of blocking writes and hasn't been developed any further since the author quickly whipped it together. Has anyone used it for high performance stuff?

What alternatives are there? Do we really need to be developing something custom?

Comment: You mean something like IIS on Windows Server?

Comment: Yeah nothing you've described makes me understand why you'd think you'd need a custom app for something like this.

Comment: Well I'm going to give up on this question because it's based on bad information. Thanks for the responses though guys...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume from the fact that you're asking this that IIS won't work for you (because if there was any chance that IIS would work, I would suggest using it instead).

You could check out [Manos](http://jacksonh.tumblr.com/post/1159500924/manos-de-mono-the-manifesto) (an entire framework with its own Web Server).

You could also try the re-distributable version of [Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/).

Comment: I keep reading in places that IIS often bottles out at 30-40 requests per second. I am willing to admit that this whole question is redundant if my sources are in fact wrong...?

Comment: Your sources are quite wrong. IIS can handle far more requests than that...just ask the StackOverflow team. Typically the bottlenecks in IIS Web Applications are poorly written code and poorly optimized IIS configurations.

Comment: 30-40 requests is preposterous.